# "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, craco

I am setting up an application with craco and typescript. Since the moment I added TS, eslint and prettier to my project I cannot compile it, because I keep getting error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  **@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions**

Lines that this error refers to are as follows:

```
async createOrUpdateModalOpen(entityDto: EntityDto): Promise<void> {
    if (entityDto.id === 0) {
        this.props.tenantStore.createTenant();
    } else {
        await this.props.tenantStore.get(entityDto);
    }

    this.setState({ tenantId: entityDto.id });
    this.Modal();

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (entityDto.id !== 0) {
            this.formRef.current?.setFieldsValue({
                ...this.props.tenantStore.tenantModel,
            });
        } else {
            this.formRef.current?.resetFields();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

And specifically line: `this.formRef.current?.setFieldsValue({`

Here are my .eslintrc.js, .prettierrc, and tsconfig.json files for reference:

#### .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    extends: [
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
    },
    rules: {
        "prettier/prettier": [
            "error",
            {
              "endOfLine": "auto"
            }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "off"
    },
    settings: {
        react: {
            version: 'detect',
        },
    },
};
```

#### .prettierrc

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "printWidth": 120,
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "semi": true,
  "endOfLine": "crlf",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ".prettierrc",
      "options": {
        "parser": "json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "scripts", "acceptance-tests", "webpack", "jest", "src/setupTests.ts"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code.Only issue is you are not returning anything fom the component. I see  `this.setState()` in your code. It should be a component then. A component must return a jsx content. Are you returning anything?

Comment: Let me know if this soles your issue